# How to fill entity's field with separate queue in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I have an entity, say

```
@Entity
public class Category {

  private String name;

  private int usersInCategory;
}
```

I want to fill usersInCategory field with some aggregating SQL query (`select count(*) ... group by ...`).

How can I do this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Formula`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) (this is an Hibernate specific annotation). From the documentation:

> #### [2.4.3.1. Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785)
>
> Sometimes, you want the Database to do
>   some computation for you rather than
>   in the JVM, you might also create some
>   kind of virtual column. You can use a
>   SQL fragment (aka formula) instead of
>   mapping a property into a column. This
>   kind of property is read only (its
>   value is calculated by your formula
>   fragment).
>
> ```
> @Formula("obj_length * obj_height * obj_width")
> public long getObjectVolume()
> ```
>
> The SQL fragment can be as complex as
>   you want and even include subselects.

As the documentation writes, the SQL fragment can be pretty complex and can reference the owning entity like in the example below  (the non aliased `id` column in the `o.customer_id=id` part of the where clause references the owning entity column):

```
@Formula("(select coalesce(extract ('day' from age(max(o.creation_date))), 9999) from Orders o where o.customer_id = id)")
private int daysSinceLastOrder;
```

#### See also

- [Hibernate Derived Properties - Performance and Portability](http://eyal-lupu.blogspot.com/2009/07/hibernate-derived-properties.html)

Comment: (+1) Link you provided is really good. But i prefer To use other Than @Formula instead such as a secondary Table mapped as a view, for instance

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. IMO, the mentioned link does a much better job than the documentation, they should include its content. Regarding Forumula vs Views, as always, it depends :)

Comment: I have not got time yet for testing, but how many requests to DB will be done when loading entity? One or two sequentially?

Comment: Well, actually there will be 1 request will embedded select, I have checked. :)

Comment: @glaz666: I answered too fast, this is exactly what the link I posted is showing :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way which has been figured out to do that is following query for retreiving:

```
select c, (select count(i) from Item i where c = i.category) from Category c
```

This will produce list of tuples (Categroy, items_count). The initial task to init entity's field won't be accomplished that way, but that will be more efficient when you don't need to have that field always.